# webview cookie bug in 10.8?

Tags: cookies, webview, webkit

I have an application that implements a web browser using webkit.  It works great in 10.7, but in 10.8 cookies that enable login to web sites work for the first website logged into, but not thereafter, unless I restart the application.  Allocating and using a second webview fails.  This appears to be some kind of cache-related problem, but I can find nothing in the 10.8 release notes that addresses this.  I know that Safari works on 10.8, so this must be solvable.  Has anybody else experienced this?  Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: SOLVED!  I had custom WebPreferences for the webView, and was turning private browsing on.  This worked fine pre-10.8, but in 10.8 it caused the problem I described.  Simply not turning it on solved the problem.